# Collision detection on multiple sources

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

Collision detection only occurs within a single source. Is there a workaround so my js generated top layer doesn't look like this? So basically what I mean is that in this example the label Dordrecht and 's-Gravendeel would need to be hidden when detecting a collision with my generated source.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature, termed "cross-source placement" is a high priority at Mapbox and under active development. You can track the feature via [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/1042).